# As 3.0 2 Complementary Sliders

Tags: actionscript-3, slider

The question is to code with AS 3.0 for 2 sliders in a way that when the first slider is incremented by a uint the other slider decreases by the same uint and vis versa.

Comment: With flex or from scratch?

Comment: Many Thanks for having asked the question. In reality I wanted to make it work with Flash (Slider) UI component. Very great if you help me with this problem. Daf/Sweden

Answer (score 0):

So [here's](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/Slider.html) the documentation for the Flash Slider class.

Here's how I would go about it:

```
// Add the sliders to the stage, lets call them `slider1` & `slider2`.
// Store each value of the slider
var slider1Position:Number = slider1.value;
var slider2Position:Number = slider2.value;
// Set liveDragging to true so the CHANGE event is fired continuously
slider1.liveDragging = true;
slider2.liveDragging = true;
// Add event listeners to listen for when they are moved. 
slider1.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, onSlider1Changing);
slider2.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, onSlider2Changing);

function onSlider1Changing(e:SliderEvent):void {
    var difference:Number = e.value - slider1Position;
    // update the position of the other slider
    slider2.value += difference;
}

function onSlider2Changing(e:SliderEvent):void {
    var difference:Number = e.value - slider2Position;
    // update the position of the other slider
    slider1.value += difference;
}
```

Try that out. I'm hoping that setting the value manually won't trigger a CHANGE event...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that it did not work. I proceeded this way for the interaction between (slider1) and (slider2) as slave.

```
var slider1Position:Number = slider1.value;
var slider2Position:Number = slider2.value;
slider2.value = 100; // max value for the sliders is 100 as an example.

slider1.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, onSlider1Changing);

function onSlider1Changing(e:SliderEvent):void {
slider1Position = e.value;
slider2.value = 100 - slider1Position;
}
```

What is missing in the whole code is the other way where slider2 is considered as activator and slider1 as slave.

I hope really not bother with my question.